# Getting form values after clicking link and returning

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I have a form that a user fills out. There's a button in the form that can allow a user to go to his profile, update it, then return back to the original form.

I'm using `{{ url()->previous() }}` for the back redirection. I tried using `{{ request('message') }}` 
  and `{{ old('message')}}` against:

```
<textarea name="message">{{request('message')}}</textarea>
```

as well as

```
<textarea name="message">{{old('message')}}</textarea>
```

I'm starting to believe there is no proper solution since its `not a form submission`

Comment: if you want to save the form data without it being submitted you'll have to do some javascript, like store it in `localStorage` and retrieve it on page load. As you said, if you do not submit the form there is no recollection of it on the php side.

Comment: I agree with @Flame. Php side you can submit with another button, check for this button in the function used for store, save the user input in session and redirect to profile page. When you return to form repopulate from session if there is something.

Comment: thats what ill do @dparoli thanks